# getting error - Unexpected "if" keyword after "@" character. Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "if" with

Tags: asp.net-mvc

im getting error in view- ""test1.cshtml"

Unexpected "if" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "if" with

**test1.cshtml**

```
    @model WebApplication9.Models.Names


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyName)

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.MyName))
    {
        <p>welcome, your name is @Model.MyName</p>
    }
}
```

controller code

```
 public ActionResult test1()
        {

            Names name = new Names();

            return View(name);

            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult test1(string name)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Hello what is ur name ???";
            ViewBag.Name = name;
            return View();
        }
```

model code

```
namespace WebApplication9.Models
{
    public class Names
    {
        public string MyName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try reading and understanding the error? Did you try doing some research after that?

Comment: ya i did research, but i started mvc today .im new in mvc

Comment: Your research doesn't show from your question. Anyway, then don't run to Stack Overflow at the first error you get, but find a decent tutorial.

Comment: @STACK2 You haven't done enough research. You can never do enough research.

Comment: getting error because . ViewBag.Name = name;in this line .name dont have data. its getting null

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
@model WebApplication9.Models.Names


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.MyName))
    {
        <p>welcome, your name is @Model.MyName</p>
    }
}
```

Since you have the `@using`, the Razor code inside it does not need the `@`. But, if you have an HTML element, then you will need to use the `@`, like on the Welcome text.

Comment: that error solved but i got one more error , if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.MyName))
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: @STACK2 You have 2 properties defined, `Name` and `MyName`. One of the two don't exist. Decide on which one you want to use and stick with it.

Comment: If it solved your primary problem that is described on question title, accept the answer plz.

Comment: "Try" is not an answer. Explain what you changed.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to add @ sign in front of "if".  The code should be like this:

```
@model WebApplication9.Models.Names
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
      Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.MyName))
     {
        <p>welcome, your name is @Model.MyName</p>
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `@` symbol in front of your `if` statement.

This is how it should look:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyName)

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.MyName))
    {
        <p>welcome, your name is @Model.MyName</p>
    }
}
```

You code is not consistent here, you are using 2 different property names, namely `Name` and `MyName`. Use only one.

You are also not populating the `MyName` property any where? You are using `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` on a property that doesn't have a set value. Try this as well:

```
public ActionResult test1()
{
     Names name = new Names();
     name.MyName = "Clown";

     return View(name);
}
```

You `Index` action method has 2 return views, remove one.

Please spend time working through some `ASP.NET MVC` tutorials. It will take some time learning but in the long run it is for the best.

Comment: both are i set to MyName still getting error

Comment: @STACK2 Yes I see that but look further up in the code, you have `m.Name`. They all need to be the same. So either `Name` or `MyName` does not exist in your model.

Comment: i have changed m.Name to m.MyName. still getting error. kindly go through my post. i provided model and controller

Comment: It's really simple then. `Name` does not exist. It is not in your model but you are still trying to use it in your view. Change it to this code in your view: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyName)`

Comment: i already changed . still getting error

Comment: Try setting a value to `MyValue` like I explained in my answer.

Comment: hey  i got it thanks..@Brendan

Comment: We have answered you initial question ages ago. Accept an answer and move on to the next post.